# Building dynamic where query from linq to ef core

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

My model looks like below

```
public class Country
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class User
{
 public int Id{get; set;}
 public string FirstName {get; set;}
 public string LastName {get; set;}
 public string Email {get; set;}
}

public class Company
{
  public int Id{get; set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string City {get; set;}
  public string Address1 {get; set;}
  public string Address2 {get; set;}
  [ForeignKey("Country")]
  public int CountryId{get; set;}

  public Country Country{get; set;}
  public ICollection<CompanyUsers> CompanyUsers {get; set;}
}

public class CompanyUsers
{
 public int Id{get; set;}
 [ForeignKye("Company")]
 public int CompanyId {get; set;}
 [ForeignKye("User")]
 public int UserId {get; set;}

 public Country Country{get; set;}
 public User User{get; set;}
}
```

I want to let user to be able to search Company record either by any property defined in `Country, Company or User class` **except Id property**

I tried looking at this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16646241/4346969) but it doesn't handle navigation property. Could someone help me to build dynamic where clause including properties from navigation property.

With this implementation I can only do as below

```
myContext.CompanyEntity
.Where(FilterLinq<CompanyEntity>
.GetWherePredicate(searchParams))
.ToList();

public class SearchField
{
  public string Key { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't see an example of your query, what did you tried?

Comment: What problem do you have with navigation properties? Do you only want to include them when something in them is used as parameter in a query?

Comment: Do you want AND or OR behavior?

Comment: Basically with the implementation of SO discussion I can't add predicate to the navigation property

Comment: @CaiusJard I want query to behave as AND

Comment: With `CompanyEntity`, you can navigate only to `Country` and it's child property... not to `User`.

Comment: @user1672994 what if I add List<CompanyUsers> navigation property in Company entity

Comment: @user1672994 start from CompanyUser then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on the idea from answer you pointed to is not that complicated.

You need to change assumption so the property name in SerchField can hold definition of property path like `Company.City` or `Company.Country.Name` as well as just property `FirstName`. And you need to handle it:

so instead of just having simple property like so:

```
Expression columnNameProperty = Expression.Property(pe, fieldItem.Name);
```

you need to handle property chain:

```
Expression columnNameProperty = GetPropertyExpression(pe, fieldItem.Name);


Expression GetPropertyExpression(Expression pe, string chain){
    var properties = chain.Split('.');
    foreach(var property in properties)
          pe = Expression.Property(pe, property);

    return pe;
}
```

Basically what this code does it applies properties over previous modifying `pe` variable on every loop creating property chain. Entity framework will process it and create appropriate joins. This will work only for single relations and not for collections.

so the modified code from that answer looks like this:

```
public class FilterLinq<T>
{
    Expression GetPropertyExpression(Expression pe, string chain)
    {
        var properties = chain.Split('.'); 
        foreach(var property in properties)
           pe = Expression.Property(pe, property);

        return pe;
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> GetWherePredicate(params SearchField[] SearchFieldList)
    {

        //the 'IN' parameter for expression ie T=> condition
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), typeof(T).Name);

        //combine them with and 1=1 Like no expression
        Expression combined = null;

        if (SearchFieldList != null)
        {
            foreach (var fieldItem in SearchFieldList)
            {
                //Expression for accessing Fields name property
                Expression columnNameProperty = GetPropertyExpression(pe, fieldItem.Name);

                //the name constant to match 
                Expression columnValue = Expression.Constant(fieldItem.Value);

                //the first expression: PatientantLastName = ?
                Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(columnNameProperty, columnValue);

                if (combined == null)
                {
                    combined = e1;
                }
                else
                {
                    combined = Expression.And(combined, e1);
                }
            }
        }

        //create and return the predicate
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Boolean>>(combined, new ParameterExpression[] { pe });
    }

}
```

Comment: it handled most of the cases but the ICollection<CompanyUsers> points to User class as well. 
while passing CompanyUsers.User.FirstName it couldn't resolve User

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer it will not work on the collections. It can be expanded to work but you would need to create an expression to call some method on the collection like `CompanyUsers.Any(x=>x.FirstName == "john")` bit more complicated but can be done

Comment: Thank you for re-iterating the edge case. I missed that part. I will handle the collection part in some ways. Thank you

Comment: in Expression e1 instead of Equal is there built in method for like query or need to have custom implementation. More like Start with (e.g. Name like 'joh%'

Comment: basically all things that you can write in a query you can produce here with expressions - expressions are a way to write code dynamically, so expression like `x.Name.StartsWith(value)` is just a method call on object of type string (from memory:) `Expression.Call( columnNameProperty, startWithMethodInfo)`